# Syntax error when inserting album track number into table as INT in SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql, sql-server, int, sql-server-2012, syntax-error

I'm trying to create this table in SQL Server 2012.

```
USE BC0

CREATE TABLE Songs 
(
TrackID INT IDENTITY NOT NULL,
Name VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
Album VARCHAR(50) PRIMARY KEY
)

INSERT INTO Songs (TrackID, Name, Album)
('1', 'High Hopes', 'High Hopes')
```

But I'm getting a `Incorrect syntax near '1'.` error.

I've tried it with `' '` and without and I'm not really sure what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need the keyword `VALUES` between the field list and the value list.

```
INSERT INTO Songs (TrackID, Name, Album) VALUES (1, 'High Hopes', 'High Hopes')
```

Also, if a field is an `IDENTITY`, then you don't give it a value.  Using `IDENTITY` is expressly asking SQL Server to sort that out for you.

```
INSERT INTO Songs (Name, Album) VALUES ('High Hopes', 'High Hopes')
```

Finally, a primary key value can only appear once in a table.  As you have the primary key on your `album` field, you will never be able to insert more than one track per album.